# Bootstrapped extension with new jpm Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I'm realizing a Firefox extension using one of the last (or the last) version of jpm (1.0.5) but the extension does not call the startup() or shutdown() methods. I know that should be mandatory to declare the extension as

```
<em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
```

into the install.rdf file, but when I have created my namespace (using jpm init) there was not this file, that it is replaced from package.json. In this case how I should modify the files to use startup and shutdown methods working?

Comment: When using jpm don't modify bootstrap.js follow this guide here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment....I'm not talking about bootstrap.js (that it is not generate from the last version of jpm) but how to make "bootstrable" the extension

Comment: What is "bootstrapable"? Using twitter bootstrap? You are using jpm, so you should not have to think about the install.rdf or bootstrap.js ever. By bootstrapble do you mean twitter bootstrap.js/bootstrap.css?

Comment: I'm talking about the type of extension inserted here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions

Comment: Oh I think see now. You stated in the first like you are using latest jpm. But then you are trying to trigger startup and shutdown events. Your addon has a bootstrap.js but it is not something you should deal with at all - force yourself not to think about it, it will confuse you. That bootstrapj.s is something totally different. If you want startup/shutdown events in jpm you should follow this guide - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

Comment: The last version of jpm create a main.js, that is the default entry point of my addon (but can be changed from package.json file). The actual problem is that I would not like to export my main.js file, but I would like to understand if I can use startup and/or shutdown methods directly in main.js file or not. And, in case of not, how I can use these methods. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can create startup/shutdown events from main.js as per that article in my previous comment. Try it out it will work for sure. I did it in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my main.js I listen for load and unload like this.

```
exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
    if (options.loadReason == "install" || options.loadReason == "startup") {
        factory = new Factory(AboutDualView);
        factory = new Factory(AboutEPFViewer);
        registerRemotePages();
    }
}

exports.onUnload = function (reason) {
    if (reason == "shutdown") {
        factory.unregister();
        RemotePageManager.removeRemotePageListener("about:dualview");
        RemotePageManager.removeRemotePageListener("about:epfviewer");
    }
};

function registerRemotePages(){
    let DualViewmanager = new RemotePages("about:dualview");
    let EPFViewmanager = new RemotePages("about:epfviewer");
}
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

Answer (score 1):

What type of add-on do you have?

Sounds like an XUL/Overlay add-on using the legacy API.  If that is the case, then you must create your own `bootstrap.js` file.  Have you gone through all the steps to [convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless)?

`jpm init` will create the bootstrap code only when using the Addons-SDK.  I'm not sure of any benefit to using jpm unless you are creating an add-on using the new Addons-SDK API, except perhaps the ability to package and submit the add-on to AMO from the command line.  The debugging/validation checks of jpm just don't seem to catch many problems, almost none in XUL/Overlay API based add-ons.

Perhaps you have looked here already? [Bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), which links to a documented skeleton [bootstrap.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/bootstrap.js).

Note, though, that in the [chrome.manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#Instructions_supported_in_bootstrapped_add_ons), the `overlay` instruction is not supported in bootstrapped extensions.

These and other topics are also covered in the "convert" document, referenced above.

Comment: In my case the addon is not XUL/overlay but is already a restartless addon. Infact, my entry point is "main.js" (autocreated using jpm init). If I create a new addon using jpm init, inserting the code from developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/bootstrap.js into my entry point file and importing all the necessary elements, I can not handle the startup and shutdown methods